# If custom field value is greater than x echo image?

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now I have a code to display an image if the custom field value is available:

```
 if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-custom-stockup', true ) ) {
        echo '<img src="http://www.website.com/images/rocket_ico.png" align="left">'; 
    } else {
    echo "";
    }
```

But I want to display the image if the value is equal or greater than 50.
I have this code so far. I guess I need to mix the above code into this one:

```
    if($usp-custom-stockup > 50)
{
    echo '<img src="http://www.website.com/images/rocket_ico.png" align="left">';
}
```

But have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps (because this is untested code), but is it possible to use something like this:

```
// ref: based on your code
// ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/#comment-316
$usp_custom_stockup = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-custom-stockup', true );
if ( ! empty($usp_custom_stockup) ) {
    if ( $usp_custom_stockup > 50 ) {
        echo '<img src="http://www.website.com/images/rocket_ico.png" align="left">'; 
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
}
// You can potentially deal with another else situation here if need be ...
```

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked and glad to be of some help! :)